# How To Create A New Angular Dart Project On VS Code

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code, angular-dart

I already installed Dart extension for VS Code and also tried ngdart but it isnt working
So I pressed CTRL+SHIFT+P And picked > Dart: New Project

but there is no option for

> Angular Dart Web App

only

> Bare-Bones Web App

> Console Application

> Dart Package

> Server App

Comment: You know that there haven't been a major release for AngularDART  for several YEARS ?

Comment: Yeah, I do know about that. But somehow people from 2 years ago can make a project on VS Code by having the Dart Extension. Did they remove support for Angular ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ngdart_cli`](https://pub.dev/packages/ngdart_cli)

```
dart pub global activate ngdart_cli
ngdart create <package_name>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since version 7.1.0 angular packages was renamed from angular_(package) to ng(package), so formerly CLI tool ngdart was renamed to ngdart_cli. More info in changelog info on pub.dev https://pub.dev/packages/ngdart/changelog#710.

Answer (score 1):

the angular_cli package and ngdart package are outdated use the ngdart_cli to create a new project using the command line